# DNS and firewall

Tags: firewall

I am new to this forum so if this is off-topic or misplaced please tell me where to ask instead.

So my problem is : I have an OpenVPN server with an public IP adress (1.2.3.4) to this server are connected some clients in a network like 10.8.0.0/24 which arent accesible with his public IP. These clients have diferrent roles (1 client is a web server another is a mail box, etc...). I also have one domain such as example.com, DNS for this domain is handled by the VPN server
I have two clients with web servers with different FQDN :
The first is www.example.com with IP 10.8.0.2
The second is box.example.com with IP 10.8.0.3
So far, I only had one web server so my domain pointed to 1.2.3.4 the VPN server forwarded all incoming traffic on port 80 and 443  to 10.8.0.2 (with NAT) and that way www.example.com was accesible from the internet.

Now, I dont know what I have to set up so the server forwards the requests to the two different boxes depending on the subdomain.

Thank you very much for your help, even if you only guide me on what to search on google I'd very grateful because I am now kind of lost.

PD: I believe to forward the mail traffic from VPN I cant use IPTABLES to forward the traffic but I need to setup a MTA proxy so I can check the SPF records correctly, otherwise I am getting that all the emails received on my box.example.com are coming from 10.8.0.1 instead of the public IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a reverse proxy on the server that currently serves ports 80 and 443. The reverse proxy then forwards subdomains to servers you want. HAProxy and nginx can be used for this.

Comment: Alright thank you very much. Do I have to set up anything special on the CNAME records on the dns?

Comment: You need to set up proper records for the subdomains.

Comment: All the CNAME records has to point to the proxy right?

Comment: You can use CNAME or A records for the subdomains.